# Overloaded functions with inherited parameter

Tags: c#, overloading, abstract-class

I'm trying to do something like this but I'm **getting an error** along the lines of:

> Cannot convert from AbstractExampleClass to SpecificExampleClassA.

So I'm probably going in the wrong direction with this code, can anyone tell me what's wrong and how to fix it.

```
public abstract class AbstractExampleClass 
{
    // Code goes here
}

public class SpecificExampleClassA : AbstractExampleClass 
{

}

public class SpecificExampleClass : AbstractExampleClass 
{

}

public class handler 
{
    public void Handle(AbstractExampleClass aec)
    {
        HandleSpecific(aec);
    }

    public void HandleSpecific(SpecificExampleClassA a)
    {
        // DoSomething
    }

    public void HandleSpecific(SpecificExampleClassB b)
    {
        // DoSomething Else
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overloading is resolved at compile time, so you can't expect it to decide which overload to call depending on the *runtime type* of `aec`. *The overload to call must be decided at compile time.*

What you really need here is the "[subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Subtyping)" kind of polymorphism (aka just "polymorphism" in C# terminology), not [ad hoc polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Ad_hoc_polymorphism) (aka "overloading").

Move the handler methods in the subclasses instead:

```
public abstract class AbstractExampleClass 
{
    public abstract void Specific();
}

public class SpecificExampleClassA : AbstractExampleClass 
{

    public override void Specific()
    {
        // DoSomething
    }
}

public class SpecificExampleClass : AbstractExampleClass 
{

    public override void Specific()
    {
        // DoSomething Else
    }
}

public class handler 
{
    public void Handle(AbstractExampleClass aec)
    {
        aec.Specific();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That can be handled by the [Visitor Pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html)

```
public abstract class AbstractExampleClass 
{
    public abstract void Accept( Handler handler );
}

public class SpecificExampleClassA : AbstractExampleClass 
{
    public override Accept( Handler handler )
    {
        handler.HandleSpecific( this );
    }
}

public class SpecificExampleClass : AbstractExampleClass 
{
    public override Accept( Handler handler )
    {
        handler.HandleSpecific( this );
    }
}

public class Handler // the Visitor
{
    public void Handle(AbstractExampleClass aec)
    {
        aec.Accept( this );
    }

    public void HandleSpecific(SpecificExampleClassA a) // visit method
    {
        // DoSomething
    }

    public void HandleSpecific(SpecificExampleClassB b) // visit method
    {
        // DoSomething Else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to do it that way, you can do:

```
    public void Handle(AbstractExampleClass aec)
    {
        switch (aec)
        {
            case SpecificExampleClassA a:
                HandleSpecific(a);
                break;
            case SpecificExampleClassB b:
                HandleSpecific(b);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception($"What do I do with a '{aec?.GetType()}'?");
        }
    }
```

But I recommend an approach like the one in Sweeper's answer if you are allowed to do that.